# Number of lines of a text file

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to make a function that takes in a file name (i.e. "data.txt") and produces the number of lines of that file.

```
data.txt :
24 42
45 54
67 76
89 98
12 21
99 99
33 33
```

The below piece of code is my attempt to build a function that takes in the filename "data.txt" and produces the number of lines of the file. The first part (lines 1-12) of the code is defining the function and the second part (lines 14-19) is where I call the function in a program. The output of the below code is 1 rarther than 7 (look up - data.txt has 7 lines).

```
function count_lines(filename) result(nlines)
  character :: filename
  integer :: nlines 
  open(10,file=filename)
  nlines = 0
  do
  read(10,*,iostat=io)
  nlines = nlines + 1
  if (io/=0) exit
  end do
  close(10)
end function count_lines

program myread 
  integer :: count_lines

  print *, count_lines("data.txt")

end program myread
```

Attempt a debuging:

I think it has something to do with the do loop not working, but I'm unsure. I have changed the if statement to `if (io>0)` and this gives an output of `2`, which I don't understand. At present I'm not getting an error outputs when I compile just the wrong output.

Comment: I don't really know fortran but I think you'll need a `do while`.

Comment: *I don't really know fortran but I think you'll need a do while*  The code has a `do` loop with a conditional `exit`; near enough a do while for most purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`filename` (the dummy argument) is only one character long. Anything might happen if you provide a longer one (usually it is capped, though). 
This does not result in an error as you did not specify the `status` of the file, or even checked whether the operation was successful (In fact, you just created a new file `d`). 
You can avoid this by using an assumed length string:

```
function count_lines(filename) result(nlines)
  character(len=*) :: filename
  ! ...

  open(10,file=filename, iostat=io, status='old')
  if (io/=0) stop 'Cannot open file! '
```

```
function count_lines(filename) result(nlines)
  implicit none
  character(len=*)    :: filename
  integer             :: nlines 
  integer             :: io

  open(10,file=filename, iostat=io, status='old')
  if (io/=0) stop 'Cannot open file! '

  nlines = 0
  do
    read(10,*,iostat=io)
    if (io/=0) exit
    nlines = nlines + 1
  end do
  close(10)
end function count_lines
```

[Increment *after* the check to ensure a correct line count.]

---

For the second part of your question:

Positive (non-zero) error-codes correspond to any error other than `IOSTAT_END` (end-of-file) or `IOSTAT_EOR` (end-of-record). After reading in the (new) file in the first round of the loop (`io==IOSTAT_END`, I checked with my compiler), you are trying to read beyond the end... This results in a positive error. Since the increment occurs *before* you exit the loop, the final value is `2`.

Comment: Thanks so much this is exactly what I needed. :)