# How to split a file with multiple columns into multiple files with two columns each using Fortran 90

Tags: file, fortran, multiple-columns, fortran90

I have a physics simulation program that generates a file with six columns, one for the time, and other five for physical properties. I need to make a Fortran 90 program that read this file, and generates five files with two columns, one for the time and another for a physical property.

I have used F90 before, but I only know how to generate files and write on them, but I have no idea how to modify a file and generate more files with data from a file.

I don't expect to have the problem solved, I just want to know where to find information. Any advice will be useful.

[I don't know *a priori* how many rows the program will generate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh9L7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**The first step** is to read in the data. In the following instructions, we will first loop over the file and count the number of rows, `nrows`. This value will be used to allocate a data array to the necessary size. We then return to the beginning of the file and read in our data in a second loop.

1. Declare an integer variable to act as a file handle/reference.
2. Declare an allocatable array of reals (floats) to hold the data.
3. Loop over the file to [count the number of lines in the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32682634/7038689). Remove header lines from the count.
4. Allocate the data array to the proper size, `(nrows,nvalues)`.
5. Return to the beginning of the file. Repeat the loop over each of the rows, reading all values from the row into your data array.
6. Close the file.

**The next step** is to create 5 new files, each containing the time and one of the 5 property measurements:

1. Loop over each of the 5 properties contained in `data`.
2. For each `j`th property, open a new file.
3. Loop over the `data` array, writing the time and `j`th property to a new line.
4. Close the file.

Here is working code you can use or modify to suit your needs:

```
program SO
    implicit none
    integer :: i, j, nrows, nvalues, funit, ios
    real, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: data
    character(len=10), dimension(5)   :: outfiles

    !! begin
    nvalues = 5
    nrows = 0
    open(newunit=funit, file='example.txt', status='old', iostat=ios)
    if (ios /= 0) then
        print *, 'File could not be opened.'
        call exit
    else
        do
            read(funit,*,iostat=ios)
            if (ios == 0) then
                nrows = nrows + 1
            elseif (ios < 0) then               !! End of file (EOF).
                exit                            !! The 'exit' stmt breaks out of the loop.
            else                                !! Error if > 0.
                print *, 'Read error at line ', nrows + 1
                call exit()                     !! The 'exit' intrinsic ends the program.
            endif                               !! We we may pass an optional exit code.
        enddo
    endif

    nrows = nrows - 1                           !! 'nrows-1': Remove column headers from count.
    if (allocated(data)) deallocate(data)       !! This test follows standard "best practices".
    allocate(data(nrows,nvalues+1))

    rewind(funit)
    read(funit, *)                              !! Skip column headers.
    do i = 1,nrows
        read(funit, *) data(i,:)                !! Read values into array.
    enddo
    close(funit)

    !! Output file names.
    outfiles = ['prop1.txt', 'prop2.txt', 'prop3.txt', 'prop4.txt', 'prop5.txt']
    do j = 1,nvalues
        open(newunit=funit, file=outfiles(j), status='replace', iostat=ios)
        if (ios /= 0) then
            print *, 'Could not open output file: ',outfiles(j)
            call exit()
        endif
        write(funit,"(a)") "time           "//outfiles(j)(1:5)
        do i = 1,nrows
            write(funit,"(f0.0,t14,es14.6)") data(i,1), data(i,j+1)
        enddo
        close(funit)
    enddo
end program SO
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which is not been tested...
It is a bit of a kindergarten approach, but it may be helpful. You could avoid the 6 array altogether, but it is often better to have the variables as separate arrays as it makes it vectorise better with contiguous memory layout. One could also read those into the 6 arrays, and avoid the 6xN array.

```
PROGRAM ABC
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL, DIMENSION(:,:) :: My_File_Data
REAL, DIMENSION(:)   :: My_Data1
REAL, DIMENSION(:)   :: My_Data2
REAL, DIMENSION(:)   :: My_Data3
REAL, DIMENSION(:)   :: My_Data4
REAL, DIMENSION(:)   :: My_Data5
REAL, DIMENSION(:)   :: My_Data6
INTEGER              :: Index, LUN, I, IO_Status

OPEN(NEWUNIT=LUN, FILE='abc.dat')
Index = 0
FirstPass: DO WHILE(.TRUE.)
  READ(UNIT=LUN,*, IO_Status)
  IF(IO_Status /= 0) EXIT  
  Index = Index + 1
ENDDO FirstPass

REWIND(LUN)
ALLOCATE(My_File_Data(Index))
ALLOCATE(My_Data1(Index))
ALLOCATE(My_Data2(Index))
ALLOCATE(My_Data3(Index))
ALLOCATE(My_Data4(Index))
ALLOCATE(My_Data5(Index))
ALLOCATE(My_Data6(Index))

SecondPass: DO I = 1, Index
  READ(UNIT=LUN,*) My_File_Data(:,I)
  Index = Index + 1
ENDDO SecondPass

DO I = 1, Index
  Data1(I) = My_File_Data(1,I)
ENDDO

! What follows is more elegant...
Data2(:) = My_File_Data(2,:)  !Where the first (:) is redundant... It seems more readable, but there are some reasons not to use it... (LTR)
Data3 = My_File_Data(3,:)
Data4 = My_File_Data(4,:)
Data5 = My_File_Data(5,:)
Data6 = My_File_Data(6,:)

DEALLOCATE(My_File_Data)

!Etc
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers want to read in everything at once. I think that's too much of a bother.

Firstly, I'd check if I even needed Fortran for that. The Linux command `cut` can be used very effectively here. For example, if your data is comma separated, you could simply use

```
for i in {1..5}; do 
    cut -d, -f1,$((i+1)) data.txt > data${i}.txt; 
done
```

to do the whole thing.

If you need Fortran, here's how I'd go about it:

1. Open all files
2. In a permanent loop, read in the whole row at once.
3. If you encounter an error, it's probably EOF, so exit the loop
4. Write the data to the output files.

Here's some basic code:

```
program split

    implicit none
    integer :: t, d(5), u_in, u_out(5)
    integer :: i
    integer :: ios

    open(newunit=u_in, file='data.txt', status="old", action="read")

    open(newunit=u_out(1), file='temperature.txt', status='unknown', action='write')
    open(newunit=u_out(2), file='pressure.txt', status='unknown', action='write')
    open(newunit=u_out(3), file='pair_energy.txt', status='unknown', action='write')
    open(newunit=u_out(4), file='ewald_energy.txt', status='unknown', action='write')
    open(newunit=u_out(5), file='pppm_energy.txt', status='unknown', action='write')

    read(u_in, *)   ! omit the column names
    write(u_out(1), *) "Time     Temperature"    
    write(u_out(2), *) "Time     Pressure"    
    write(u_out(3), *) "Time     Pair Energy"    
    write(u_out(4), *) "Time     Ewald Energy"    
    write(u_out(5), *) "Time     PPPM Energy"

    do
        read(u_in, *, iostat=ios) t, d
        if (ios /= 0) exit
        do i = 1, 5
            write(u_out(i), *) t, d(i)
        end do
    end do

    close(u_in)
    do i = 1, 5
        close(u_out(i))
    end do

end program split
```

Cheers